# Avengers: Age of Ultron - "Sokovia" filming location?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, film-location

I am talking about a specific scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (at ~00:04:17 (+/-)), it is shortly after Stark's iron legion lands on Sovakia's streets declaring that the area is not safe and they are here to help.

While watching this particular scene, I noticed chips on a food stand, those are "Ādažu čipsi" and "Kartupeļu salmiņi", and they are both Latvian products. That's where from the question comes - were there any scenes of Sovakia filmed in Latvia or nearby? Or is there perhaps another connection?

[image: Latvian products: "Ādažu čipsi" & "Kartupeļu salmiņi"]

Comment: Signs are on Serbian, for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not even close. [The bulk of Sokovia scenes were film in the UK.](http://filmlondon.org.uk/april2015)

> As a superhero film with big budget and big action, The Avengers: Age of Ultron needed a large amount of outdoor space with a high degree of flexibility in which to construct their exact and closed-off worlds.
> The Peel Training Centre at the Hendon Police College was perfectly suited for the role: a blank canvas and vast space in which to construct realistic exteriors – which were to be destroyed on screen!
>
> "Over a period of five months, [Marvel Films] were able to take control over an unprecedented collection of redundant buildings, streets and real estate for several major set builds, to create and film our scenes at the heart of war-torn 'Sokovia', an Eastern European City."

Hendon Police College in London serves as the city of Sokovia:

> Hendon Police College is the principal training centre for London's Metropolitan Police Service. Founded with the official name of the Metropolitan Police College, the college is today officially called the Peel Centre, although its original name is still used frequently.

Comment: Well then, i will try to contact "Ādažu čipsi", see what they can tell about this.

Comment: @Lettmannen please do and post back here. I tried searching for some statement but all i can find is people pointing it out in Latvian.

Comment: They did mention that they do sell their products in countries like Azerbaijan. I never would have imagined that they sell our products across so many borders. Then it doesn't surprise that they sell them UK as well. Well i guess that kind of make sense. If they were filming scenes in Latvia, we would probably have heard about it. Kind of big event.

Comment: The chips may be imported to special food stores in the UK. I live near several shops that stock polish products. They may also have been purchased by the production crew specifically for authenticity.

Answer (score -3):

Well Sovokia is meant to be located in Latveria (named after Latvia) so the latvian products would make a lot of sense... Latvia=(isolated small European country located in the baltic region) Latveria=(isolated small European country located in the banat region)  But the thing is they have never said that Latveria is named after Latvia even with all the similarities like the name of the country, the description (isolated, small, european), the region (banat) and now even the products! xD

P.S. I'm Latvian, and I only found out Latveria existed today but I finally have something to tell my British friends!

Comment: Sokovia is 100% not meant to be located in Latveria, as the film rights to Latveria belong to 20th Century Fox.